# Why can't I shoot tethered with my camera while connected to the computer?

Tags: canon, magic-lantern

I am trying to take photos while the camera is connected to the computer. As soon as the camera is connected to to PC the camera changes its mode to busy. Actually, the camera is treated as a USB drive. I have Magic Lantern installed on the camera. I would like to trigger the camera to take pictures while it is connected to the computer.

Comment: Which Canon camera are you using?

Comment: Check if you can do so by WiFi or Bluetooth.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use some sort of software that can perform tethered shooting. Simply plugging a camera into the computer's USB port will by default, as you've discovered, treat the camera/card like an external drive.  You must have and run an application that can recognize a Canon dSLR and communicate with it to transfer/display files for shooting.

Something like Adobe Lightroom, or Canon's on free [EOS Utility](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/self-help-center/eos-utility) will work for this, for camera models they support (there may be some they do not, so which camera model you're using is necessary to determine if you can do this.

Magic Lantern does not add tethering capability to any camera or software application that cannot do it.

Alternatively, some wi-fi enabled cameras that cannot be tethered to a computer (e.g., the M2), can communicate with the smartphone/tablet Canon Connect app.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't know your camera model it may or may not have tethering capabilities for PC programs.
For example some DSLR Nikon cameras like 3xxx series usually don't support tethering with native software, lightroom or Photoshop.
However you can use digiCamControl under windows or Entangle under Linux systems to take pictures via USB cable and do live preview on your PC screen.
You could try with your Canon as these software supports multiple camera brands.

Answer (score 1):

Use EOS Utility.

Once the camera and EOS Utility have initialized a connection the camera will return to a normal state that will allow you to operate it normally. To send each image directly to the computer as it is taken, choose the "Remote Shooting" option. You can operate the camera directly or via the EOS Utility application.

If you want to see the results on the computer's screen as you shoot, you'll need to use a photo application, such as Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* or *Adobe Lightroom/ACR* and have EOS utility set to send the images to a folder monitored by the photo application.